# Блок расшифровки не работает не расшифровывает текст. Как исправить?

Tags: java

Есть созданный мною интерфейс программы:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ProgramScytale {

JTextArea tArea;
JTextArea tArea1;
JPanel p1;
JButton button0;
JButton button1;
JButton button2;
JScrollPane scroll;
JScrollPane scroll1;

 String Message;
 String SPARTAMessage;
 int length;

ProgramScytale(){

    JFrame window = new JFrame ("Шифр древней спарты");     
    p1 =new JPanel(null);

    tArea = new JTextArea();
    tArea.setLineWrap(true);
    tArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    tArea.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 16));

    button0 =new JButton ("ЗАШИФРОВАТЬ");
    button0.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src\\images\\icon1.jpg"));
    TActionListener actionListener = new TActionListener();
    button0.addActionListener(actionListener);
    button0.setBounds(10, 205, 195, 50);

    button1 =new JButton ("ДЕШИФРОВАТЬ");
    button1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src\\images\\icon2.jpg"));
    TActionListener1 actionListener1 = new TActionListener1();
    button1.addActionListener(actionListener1);
    button1.setBounds(390, 205, 195, 50);

    scroll = new JScrollPane(tArea);
    scroll.setBounds(10, 265, 575, 100);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );

    tArea1 =new JTextArea();
    tArea1.setLineWrap(true);
    tArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    tArea1.setEditable(false);
    tArea1.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 16));

    scroll1 = new JScrollPane(tArea1);
    scroll1.setBounds(10, 10, 575, 150);
    scroll1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );

    window.add(p1);
    p1.add(scroll);
    p1.add(button0);
    p1.add(button1);
    p1.add(scroll1);

    centeringFrame(600,400,window);                         // Вызываем метод центрирования для созданного окна
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  // Завершаем программу при закрытии окна
    window.setVisible(true);                                // Делаем окно видимым
    window.setResizable(false);

}

private static void centeringFrame (int sizeWidth, int sizeHeight, JFrame frame){  // Метод  принимает размеры окна (ширину и высоту), а также его название
    Dimension s = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int X = (s.width - sizeWidth) / 2;
    int Y = (s.height - sizeHeight) / 2;
    frame.setBounds(X, Y, sizeWidth, sizeHeight);
}   

public class TActionListener implements ActionListener {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

         Message = tArea.getText();
         tArea.setText(null);

         length = Message.length();
         int n =(((Integer) (length-1)/4)+1);
         String s = new String();
         for(int i = 0;i <n; i++){
             for(int j = 0;j < 4; j++)
             {
                 try{
                     s+=Message.charAt(i+n*j);
                 }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                     s+=" ";
                 }
             }
         }
         SPARTAMessage = s;
         Message = "";

         tArea1.setText(null);
         tArea1.append(SPARTAMessage);
     }
}

public class TActionListener1 implements ActionListener {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

         SPARTAMessage= tArea1.getText();

         int n =(((Integer) (length-1)/4)+1);
         char[] s = new char[SPARTAMessage.length()];
         int number =0;
         for(int i = 0; i < n;i++){
             for(int j = 0;j < 4; j++)
             {
                 s[i+n*j]= SPARTAMessage.charAt(number);
                 number++;
             }
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            Message+=s[i];
         };  
         tArea.setText(null);
         tArea.append(Message);

     }   
}     

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProgramScytale pro = new ProgramScytale();
}
}
```

Блок расшифровки не работает, не расшифровывает текст. Как исправить? Очень нужна помощь.

```
public class TActionListener1 implements ActionListener {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

         SPARTAMessage= tArea.getText();

         int n =(((Integer) (length-1)/4)+1);
         char[] s = new char[SPARTAMessage.length()];
         int number =0;
         for(int i = 0; i < n;i++){
             for(int j = 0;j < 4; j++)
             {
                 s[i+n*j]= SPARTAMessage.charAt(number);
                 number++;
             }
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            Message+=s[i];
         };  

         tArea1.append(Message);
     }   
}
```

1)  Алгоритм Шифрования Шифр Скитала.

2) Если использую в графическом стиле, возникают ошибки

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at ProgramScytale$TActionListener1.actionPerformed(ProgramScytale.java:121)
```

3) Я именно пробовал сначала консольный вариант. Дело в том, что если использовать эти два алгоритма вот так

```
public class SPARTA {
    static String Message="Привет";
    static String SPARTAMessage;

    int length;

    public void SHIFR(){
        this.length = Message.length();
        int n =(((Integer) (length-1)/4)+1);
        String s = new String();
        for(int i = 0;i <n; i++){
            for(int j = 0;j < 4; j++)
            {
                try{
                    s+=Message.charAt(i+n*j);
                }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                    s+=" ";
                }
            }
        }
        SPARTAMessage = s;
    }
    public void deSHIFR(){
        int n =(((Integer) (length-1)/4)+1);
        char[] s = new char[SPARTAMessage.length()];
        int number =0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j < 4; j++)
            {
                s[i+n*j]= SPARTAMessage.charAt(number);
                number++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            Message+=s[i];
        };  
    }
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
       SPARTA obj = new SPARTA();
       obj.SHIFR();
       System.out.println(SPARTAMessage);
       obj.deSHIFR();
       System.out.println(Message);
    }
}
```

все работает, но если пытаюсь вызвать отдельно метод расшифрования, то выдает null.

Comment: Во-первых, напишите (в вопросе), как должны работать алгоритмы шифрования и расшифрования. Во-вторых, что именно означает "не расшифровывает текст" (выдаёт неправильный текст, вообще ничего не происходит, ...)? В-третьих, попробуйте реализовать алгоритм без графического интерфейса, просто функциями в консольной программе, типа `String plaintext = "какой-то текст"; String encrypted = encrypt(plaintext); String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted); System.out.println(decrypted.equals(plaintext));`

Comment: @Roman  Уточнил как вы просили.

Answer (score 0):

Видно, что в консольном и в графическом вариантах алгоритмы шифрования/расшифрования одинаковые.Ошибка такая возникает, если вы пытаетесь расшифровать строку, не являющуюся корректным зашифрованным текстом. Вставьте в нижнее (текстовое) поле результат шифрования и всё сработает.

В целом, вам надо решить, что должна делать программа при попытке расшифровать некорректный текст: можно оставить текущее поведение и сказать, что так и задумано, можно адаптировать алгоритм, чтобы он проверял входной текст на соответствие условиям шифра.

Comment: Да действительно если ставлю результат нижнее поле шифрования, то все нормально. Хотелось бы конечно что бы результат обоих действий отображался в верхнем поле, но может и так сойдет.